# angular5 testing - iframe safe pipe - bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl is not a function - ERROR

Tags: angular, angular-test

I have Angular5 Project and we are loading external sites at our component using iframe with Safe Pipe (custom pipe with DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl  converting site url).  Application is working very well (by loading the site content).

While writing the test case, we are getting below error.

```
Chrome 66.0.3359 (Windows 10 0.0.0) DummyComponent toggle button check FAILED
    TypeError: this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl is not a function
        at SafePipe.transform (webpack:///./src/app/safe.pipe.ts?:21:31)
```

Here is the Whole test case bootstarping.

```
describe('DummyComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        NoopAnimationsModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot()],
      declarations: [DummyComponent, SafePipe],
      providers: [NotificationService, TranslateService, DomSanitizer],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

   it('load content', () => {
     // expecting content is loading
     ....
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that where you are calling the `pipe` you are not assigning a type of `pipe` to be used. In the Component HTML make sure that it is similar to

```
<div [innerHTML]="description | safe: 'html'"></div>
```

Important here is that after `| safe:` there is the type of `DomSanitizer` to apply.